# When do I need to deallocate memory?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory-management

I am using this code inside a class to make a webbrowser control visit a website:

```
void myClass::visitWeb(const char *url)
{
    WCHAR buffer[MAX_LEN];
    ZeroMemory(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, MB_ERR_INVALID_CHARS, url, strlen(url), buffer, sizeof(buffer)-1);

    VARIANT vURL;
    vURL.vt = VT_BSTR;
    vURL.bstrVal = SysAllocString(buffer);

    // webbrowser navigate code...

    VariantClear(&vURL);
}
```

I call visitWeb from another void function that gets called on the handlemessage() for the app. 
Do I need to do some memory deallocation here?, I see vURL is being deallocated by VariantClear but should I deallocate memory for buffer?
I've been told that in another bool I have in the same app I shouldn't deallocate anything because everything clear out when the bool return true/false, but what happens on this void?

Comment: Please, don't say "another void" when you mean "another function returning void".  When you understand that you're dealing with many functions, and the only difference is the return type, you'll see the similarities.

Comment: It seems "another bool" refers to "another function returning a bool". That in turn suggests that he doesn't understand how variables go out of scope. The return type doesn't affect this at all, and in fact variables can go out of inner scopes even before a function returns.

Comment: BTW, you have a buffer overflow. The last parameter to MultiByteToWideChar should be `MAX_LEN` (number of characters). You currently pass `MAX_LEN * sizeof(WCHAR)` (number of bytes). And you don't need to pass strlen(url); pass -1 instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have some fundamental problems with your understanding of memory management.  In this case, no, you don't need to explicitly free any memory.  You didn't ever call `new`, so you don't need to call `delete`.  `buffer` exists only on the stack, and will vanish when this method returns.

Answer (score 3):

If I might, I'd suggest doing this a bit differently -- I'd start by creating a small class:

```
class bstr { 
    VARIANT content;
public:
    bstr(char const *url) { 
        WCHAR buffer[MAX_LEN] = {0};
        MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 
                            MB_ERR_INVALID_CHARS, 
                            url, 
                            strlen(url), 
                            buffer, 
                            sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(buffer[0])-1);
        content.V_T = VT_BSTR;
        content.bstrVal = SysAllocString(buffer);        
    }

    operator VARIANT const &() { return content; }

    ~bstr() { VariantClear(&content); }
};
```

Then your code would change to something like:

```
void myClass::visitWeb(const char *url) {
    your_control.Navigate(bstr(url));
}
```

and all the allocation and freeing gets handled automatically from there.

Even if you don't do use a class like this, note the change to the call to `MultiByteToWideChar`. The last parameter is supposed to be the number of `WCHAR` elements in the buffer, not the number of `char`s. As it is, you've set up a buffer overrun...

Comment: Im not using std, i just started learning cpp and i want to finish this project before learning how to use the std namespace. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @extintor:in this case, removing that is no problem (already done).

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any `new`s, so I wouldn't expect any `delete`s.

I guess I'd look at the description of `SysAllocString()` to see if it allocates any memory that you need to get rid of yourself.

Comment: Thanks, I read VariantClear() take care of what SysAllocString() allocated.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably all you'd need to worry about, then.

Comment: Correct; VariantClear knows it has to call `SysFreeString` because `vURL.vt == VT_BSTR`.